# Under which conditions does and i.i.d family of RV have a continuous version?

Tags: probability

I am supposed to find conditions such that if and only if these conditions hold, the i.i.d family $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ has a continuous version, i.e. there exists a continuous family $Y_t$ s.th. $P(X_t = Y_t)=1$ holds.

Can anyone give me a small hint to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: (Small) hint: degenerate.

Comment: You might also want to consider the following question: If $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of iid random variables, then under which assumptions does the pointwise limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ exist (almost surely)?

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
@zhoraster: So a good try would be to consider a.s. constant random variables?

saz: Ok, but I am not sure how this will help me to be honest :)

Comment: If distribution is degenerate, then the process clearly has continuous version. Vice versa, use saz's hint: If $X_t<a$ and $X_t>b$ with positive probability for some $a<b$, then the sequence in question can't be convergent.